# Taregeting google chrome using HTML

Tags: html, firefox, browser, targeting

I want to targer google chrome , firefox and opera Using HTML

i have this code for Internet Explorer

```
<!--[if IE ]> test <![endif]-->
```

waiting for good answer

thanks

Comment: Please share what you have tried instead of waiting for the solution to be handed to you.

Answer (score -2):

firefox:

```
<!if firefox>
    test
<![endif]>
```

chrome:

```
<!if chrome>
    test
<![endif]>
```

opera

```
<!if opera>
    test
<![endif]>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but couldn't work (see link : http://filmsblog.me/target/default.html

Comment: The only other way there is to do this is through javascript/php.

PHP: `$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` then check what browser it is.